# Overlay which can rearrange the way a window is rendered?

Tags: windows, windows-10, image-processing, display

This is a read-only window which display data.

I want the red box go right, and the blue box to go left, when it's being displayed in real time.

Is there some software that can define two sub-regions, and switch them or move them around, when the image gets rendered on my screen?

[image]

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer cause it is unknown how the shown program/component implemented. If it is a multi-column list view it may be possible to hook/modify the binary and reverse the two columns, but if the data is directly painted by a custom logic I don't think this is feasible in reasonable time.

Comment: @Robert The software is written in C++. I have done some basic C++ coding before, but never any kind of reverse engineering or decompilation or "hook/modify the binary" before. Where would one start? If you could give me 3 or 4 keywords to google as my jumping off point, I'd much appreciate that.

Comment: If you are new to reverse engineering then it will be a hard start for you. The two starting points I can recommend is 1. Ghidra or IDA Free for decompiling and looking at the assembler code and functions plus 2. [Frida](https://frida.re) as a system for dynamically hook and modify programs at run-time. But the hardest task for you is most likely learning X86 or X86_64 assembler for understanding what the decompiler is showing because the generated C code e.g. by Ghidra is usually just a guess with some mistakes.